# javascript confirm dialog issues

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I have some troubles with confirm dialog not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome.

html code looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Odjava" value="Remove selected link" onclick="return odjava(somelink,'Do you really want to remove ')"/>
```

javascript code looks like this:

```
function odjava(link,text)
{
    if(link=="" || text=="")
        return false;
    return confirm(text + link + " ?");
}
```

With Chrome, everything is ok - onClick generates "confirm" dialog, and if user answer with "yes", form is submitted, otherwise it's not. Firefox doesen't show "confirm" dialog, it just submits the form.

Why's that? What am i doing wrong?

******EDIT:
I got it! I just changed my javascript to look like this:

```
function odjava(text)
{
    var linkovi = document.getElementById('linkovi');
    link = linkovi.options[linkovi.selectedIndex].text
    if(link=="" || text=="")
        return false;
    return confirm(text + link + " ?");
}
```

and it's working. It turn out that Chrome can find element in document even without document.getElementById, FF can't (won't)!

Comment: alias for some http link. it's not under "'" because it's a value from "select" - links.options[links.selectedIndex].text

Comment: That works fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `somelink` defined safely in both Firefox and Chrome?

When I try your code it works successfully in both FF and Chrome if `someLink` is defined, and fails to work as you describe in both if it is not defined.

Comment: somelink = links.options[links.selectedIndex].text

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this before, but did a bit of googling, and came up with the following:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1431250&page=10

Seems a little hokey to me, but thought I would point it out anyway. Looks like they recommend putting an extra "return false;" in the onclick after the function call.

Comment: That is not necessary here, as there's already a `return` in the onclick string.

Comment: Yes, same is true in that link. They are claiming that with firefox it maybe doesn't wait for the return from the first function call? I dunno, like I said, seems hokey, but they said it fixed the issue.

Comment: well the thing is that the code works perfectly well in Firefox already :-)